# Dash tooltip not aligning with specified target

Tags: css, python-3.x, tooltip, plotly-dash, dashboard

I am having an issue with dbc tooltip not aligning properly with the target item. See the sample code and image below, however i have found if i had more tooltips within the same dbc.Row all of the tool tips pop up in the same spot (on the far left). I really cannot explain the behavior as the majority of the time the tooltip pops up are no way near the target item. Periodically this seems to work intermittently, then goes back to popping up on the far left..

I have tried using buttons instead of an icon and see the same behavior. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

I a running python 3.9.13 with the following packages:

```
dash==2.6.0
dash-bootstrap-components==1.2.0
dash-bootstrap-templates==1.0.8
dash-core-components==2.0.0
dash-html-components==2.0.0
dash-table==5.0.0
dash-table-experiments==0.6.0
```

Here is sample code which reproduces the problem i am seeing:

```
import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import html

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP, dbc.icons.BOOTSTRAP])

#p2_icon = html.I(className="fa fa-info-circle fa-1x", id="info-icon")
p2_icon = html.I(className="bi bi-info-circle me-2", id="info-icon")
p2_info_tooltip = dbc.Tooltip("Tool tip", target="info-icon")

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("My Dash App"),
    dbc.Row([
       dbc.Col([], width="1"),
        dbc.Col([],width="1"),
        dbc.Col([
            p2_icon,
            p2_info_tooltip,
        ]),
    ]),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly for me, as it should. The tooltip is on the left, not like your image.

Comment: Finally was able to upgrade python and dash to the latest versions currently available, and I no longer see this issue.